# window.innerWidth in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, resolution

here's my code:

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div id="slider" class="slider">
        <p>Slider content</p>
    </div>
    <script src="jas.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
var divPos = 50;
var direction = "L";

function preparepage() {
    document.getElementById("slider").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("slider").style.left = divPos + "px";
    document.getElementById("slider").style.top = "50px";
    animateDiv = setInterval(beginAnimate,50);
}

function beginAnimate () {
    if (direction == "L") {
        divPos+=50;
        if (divPos == 1300) {
            direction = "R";
        }
    } else if (direction == "R"){
        divPos-=50;
        if (divPos == 150) {
            direction = "L";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("slider").style.left = divPos + "px";
}

window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(preparepage,200);
};
```

I want #slider to go from left to right and when it reaches certain point to go back. My code works fine, but I tried it this way:

```
if (direction == "L") {
    divPos+=50;
    if (divPos == window.innerWidth - 300) {
        direction = "R";
    }
}
```

and it goes left for ever.
Why is that happening?
What can I do to make it go back at certain point, no what what screen resolution is?

Comment: Maybe you should use `>` rather than `==`? You might not hit **exactly** `innerWidth-300`.

Comment: That's it, @Barmar! Thank you. As far as I know I can't mark your answer as correct because it's a comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
if (divPos > window.innerWidth - 300) {
```

Unless the window's width is a multiple of 50, incrementing `divPos` by 50 won't hit `innerWidth - 300` exactly, so you need to be less exacting.

Comment: Could you add more detail to your answer? While short answers may help by pointing in the right direction, it would be helpful to have further explanation.